# The Nine Tails game

Tags: java, graph, combinations

Nine coins are placed in a three-by-three matrix with
some face up and some face down. A legal move is to take any coin that is face up and
reverse it, together with the coins adjacent to it (this does not include coins that are diagonally
adjacent). The task is to find the minimum number of moves that lead to all coins
being face down.

The problem can be reduced to the shortest path problem and solved using BST.

We find all the possible combinations of the 9 coins, and create an `UnweightedGraph`. Each state (or combination) of the nine coins represents a node in the graph. We assign an edge from node v to u if there is a legal move from u to v.

Here's the algorithm to find all the 512 possible combinations

```
for (int u = 0; u < 512; u++) {
        char[] node = getNode(u);
        /* .....   */
}

public static char[] getNode(int index) {
    char[] result = new char[9];

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      int digit = index % 2;
      if (digit == 0)
        result[8 - i] = 'H';
      else
        result[8 - i] = 'T';
      index = index / 2;
    }

    return result;
}
```

How is this algorithm working?

I've only embedded the part I can't understand. If you want I can embed the whole `nineTailsProblem`.

Comment: I don't know.   Is it working?  What happened when you ran it?  Did it return what you expected?

Comment: It's working. Everything's good. I just can't understand its working. What's the Maths behind it?

Comment: Try debugging step by step and see what the coed is doing

Comment: I tried. I know what the code is doing and I can see how. What I can't understand is the maths/logic behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic behind this is that when iterating u=[0, 512), u's binary representation gives you all possible 9-bit combinations of `1`s and `0`s.

Example with u=[0, 8):

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

`getNode` just converts these u's to `char[]`, representing bit value `0` with `H` (head) and `1` with `T` (tail).

This gives you the value of least significant bit (LSB):

```
int digit = index % 2;
```

and division by `2` shifts the bits to the right by one, so that in the next iteration, you'll get the 2nd, then 3rd, 4th bit and so on:

```
index = index / 2;
```